# JavaScript point counter for a html snake like game

Tags: javascript, html, 2d-games

I'm new to learning JavaScript, I’ve searched many websites, and cannot find a solution so far.

I am making a mini-game on a base of snake, Can anybody help me make a point counter using javascript and html,

You can check out the game here!

https://github.com/LiquidSlime/Worm-game

and i would like to have it done using

```
<div id="points"<h1></h1></div>
and javascript;
var element = document.getElementById("points")
**Code here**;
```

hopefully someone can help me out!

Comment: `element.querySelector('h1').innerText = points;`? (needs to be called again whenever `points` changes, obviously, and will only work if typos are no longer an issue)

Comment: Typo is a reason? Element ID - `pints`, you searching for `points`.

Comment: no but thank you, i actually don't know how to integrate my worm game and a h1 point counter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a span with the id points

```
<span id=points>? Points</span>
```

Then in js change the `innnerText`

```
const pointElement = document.getElementById('points')

function updatePoints(points) {
  pointElement.innerText = points + ' Points'
}
```

Then run the update points

```
updatePoints(1)

// If you want to load if from another varible

// get points from somewhere else

updatePoints(points)
```

When you want it to update something would be like this in your code

```
points++;
updatePoints(points)
```

Comment: updatePoints(1)

if var i = index + 1; i < worm.cells.length; i++

updatePoints(points)
something like this? @hi12167pies

Comment: @MaximShevchenko You don't need `updatePoints(1)` the `updatePoints` function just writes the number that is imputed to your points element, so this changes your points to 1, then after your points updated again (at the end), so the first `updatePoints(1)` not needed